# Update Set_Area from geometry

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry

I am very new at PostgreSQL / PostGIS. I have got a table with geometry column set in (Polygon,32733), so I would like to update the Area column so as to see the area of each polygon.

I tried this:

```
ALTER TABLE public."EDIFICIO_2" ADD COLUMN area double precision;
update "EDIFICIO_2" set area = ST_AREA(Polygon,32733);
```

But the code gave no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the geometry column

```
 update "EDIFICIO_2" set area = ST_AREA(myGeometryColumn);
```